# Why is this unresolved overloaded function type error?

Tags: multithreading, c++11

While compiling I am getting error

```
#include<iostream>
#include<thread>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int a=100;

void div()
{
        if(a!=0) int div1 = 100/a;
}

void assign()
{
        a=0;
}

int main()
{
        vector<thread> Threads;

        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
                Threads.push_back(thread(div));
                Threads.push_back(thread(assign));
        }
}
```

g++ div.cpp -std=c++11 -pthread

```
div.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
div.cpp:24:31: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::thread::thread(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
   Threads.push_back(thread(div));
                               ^
In file included from div.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:133:7: note: candidate: template<class _Callable, class ... _Args> std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...)
       thread(_Callable&& __f, _Args&&... __args)
       ^
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:133:7: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
div.cpp:24:31: note:   couldn't deduce template parameter ‘_Callable’
   Threads.push_back(thread(div));
                               ^
In file included from div.cpp:2:0:
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:128:5: note: candidate: std::thread::thread(std::thread&&)
     thread(thread&& __t) noexcept
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:128:5: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ‘std::thread&&’
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:122:5: note: candidate: std::thread::thread()
     thread() noexcept = default;
     ^
/usr/include/c++/5/thread:122:5: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

I am not able to understand what is the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard function named `div` in `<cstdlib>`. `div` is a C function so it is permitted to be placed in the global namespace. The compiler doesn't know which `div` to use.

You are including `<cstdlib>` indirectly via one of the system headers used in your program, since a C++ header may include other C++ headers.

You should not try to define names that conflict with the C standard library. Rename your `div` function, or use your own namespace.

In addition, it is recommended to use `emplace_back` instead of `push_back`:

```
Threads.emplace_back(div);
```

This creates the thread directly and avoids creation of a temporary and moving from it.

Also, `using namespace std;` is not recommended, since this brings the entire C++ standard library to the scope, potentially making your program hit more conflicts like this one.

Comment: push_back wasn't working at all. Though slower shouldn't it be still working?

Comment: I mean, when I replaced div with div_test, it was still giving error for push_back. When I replaced it with emplace_back it compiled successfully. My question is, though push_back creates a temporary still shouldn't it have compiled successfully?

Comment: @InQusitive Worked for me [or at least compiled](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c98e62ff26cb89ec). Don't forget to replace `div` in all places in your program. You need to [join the threads](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c44d6a7c59b9e326) before leaving the scope. This still has a race condition, use atomic types or thread synchronisation to fix.